# Private nsswitch or nscd per process

Tags: caching, nfs, nis

I want a short term fix for some NIS performance problems on my network.

I don't have root access, and nscd has all caching turned off.

I'd like to provide local nscd-like capability to allow getpwuid to cache its results, avoiding many expensive NIS lookups (sometimes 5-10 seconds each)

context:

R calls getpwuid lots during package loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an easy or elegant way to do this. One option would be to implement your own getpwuid function and provide it to R using [LD_PRELOAD](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7795), but you'll probably be better off just getting someone to fix NIS.

Comment: since I posted I actually did what you suggest, but it's not a full solution - I'll wait and see what comes and accept your answer if nothing else.

Comment: I would love to know if there's some way to do a per-process or other fine grained nsswitch configuration, but I've never seen it.

Comment: I'm sticking with your solution.